# cron job for backup only selected tables not whole database in mysql

Tags: mysql, backup, dump

I am using the following cron job for backup my database daily.

```
    /usr/bin/mysqldump -u UNAME -p PSSW databasename > /home/mysite/stock/backup.sql
```

But I want to backup only some of the tables not whole database. Is it possible with cron job?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables

Comment: sorry, I did not check stackexchange.com. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just specify the table names along with mysqldump something as

```
mysqldump -u uname -pPSSW dbname table1 table2 table3 tableN > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -ignore-table option from the mysqldump.

mysqldump -u user -p dbname -ignore-table=table1-ignore-table=table2 > filename

Comment: there should be -- before ignore: mysqldump --u user --p psw dbname --ignore-table=table1 --ignore-table=table2 > filename

Comment: One more correction (I am learning by experiencing :)): mysqldump --u user --p psw dbname --ignore-table=dbname.table1 --ignore-table=dbname.table2 > filename